# Rancher: EC2 hosts not shown in Rancher UI

Tags: rancher

I used docker-machine to create a Rancher setup running on Virtualbox. I then added two hosts, also on virtualbox. Now, I'm trying to add a EC2 host to that setup (this is just to experiment with Rancher).

I have seen [this](http://docs.rancher.com/os/running-rancheros/cloud/aws/) tutorial, however I wanted to use Docker-machine instead.

To that extend, I have done the following:

```
 MAC-OSX:~ wauterw$ docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-84fd6de0 --amazonec2-region eu-west-1 --amazonec2-ami ami-c5f1beb6 --amazonec2-ssh-user rancher Rancher-node-aws-01
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(Rancher-node-aws-01) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with rancheros...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env Rancher-node-aws-01
```

Note: the AMI ID corresponds to rancheros-v0.7.0-hvm-1.

I then SSH into the EC2 host and execute the following command (generated in the custom method of Rancher)

```
MAC-OSX:~ wauterw$ docker-machine ssh Rancher-node-aws-01
[rancher@Rancher-node-aws-01 ~]$
[rancher@Rancher-node-aws-01 ~]$
[rancher@Rancher-node-aws-01 ~]$
[rancher@Rancher-node-aws-01 ~]$ sudo docker run -e CATTLE_HOST_LABELS='Name=Rancher-aws-node-01'  -d --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.0.2 http://192.168.99.100:8080/v1/scripts/BF48C4313C4967A7A57F:1478602800000:IAfyWoj0bPbeM1uxxFlnRgDf2o
Unable to find image 'rancher/agent:v1.0.2' locally
v1.0.2: Pulling from rancher/agent

5a132a7e7af1: Pull complete
fd2731e4c50c: Pull complete
28a2f68d1120: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
7fa4fac65171: Pull complete
33de63de5fdb: Pull complete
d00b3b942272: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b0b532d1e891534779d0eb1a01a5717ebfff9ac024db4412ead87d834ba92544
Status: Downloaded newer image for rancher/agent:v1.0.2
7d419ead09365347e827bee24519547c9507fb36ecac794ea6d4bcb312abeb55
[rancher@Rancher-node-aws-01 ~]$
```

I was expecting my Rancher UI to show also this host, but it only shows the Virtualbox hosts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Host agents need to be able to connect to the server using the registration URL, which you have set to http://192.168.99.100:8080. That is not going to be reachable by a VM in EC2.